# Variable length array

Tags: java, beginner

I just started learning java and wrote this variable length array as my first program. I wanted people's opinion on how "java" this code is. For example coding conventions, idioms that I could have used or any improvements that could be made.

**MyClass.java**:

```
package myproject;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        MyArray array = new MyArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) array.Push(i);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.Get()[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

**MyArray.java**:

```
package myproject;

public class MyArray {
    public MyArray() {
        array = new int[size];
    }
    
    public MyArray(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        array = new int[size];
    }
    
    public int[] Get() {
        return array;
    }
    
    public void Push(int number) {
        if (currentIndex >= size) {
            IncreaseArraySize();
        }
        array[currentIndex] = number;
        currentIndex++;
    }
    
    int Size() {
        return currentIndex;
    }
    
    private void IncreaseArraySize(){
        if (size == 0){
            size++;
        }
        else {
            size *= 2; 
        }
        
        int newArray[] = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = newArray;
    }
    
    private int size = 0;
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private int[] array;
}
```

I was also kind of sceptical of this line : `array = newArray;` at first but the program seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advice 1**

```
public MyArray() {
    array = new int[size];
}
```

Above, `size` is 0, so you are allocating a zero-length array. Useless. Consider this:

```
private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10; // Or some other reasonable constant but 10.

public MyArray() {
    array = new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
}
```

**Advice 2**

```
    ...
    private int size = 0;
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private int[] array;
}
```

You put your fields after everything else. The conventional portion of a Java file for fields is right after static constants and right before constructors:

```
private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

private int size = 0;
private int currentIndex = 0;
private int[] array;

public MyArray() {
    ...
}
```

**Advice 3**

Once again, the fields:

```
private int size = 0;
private int currentIndex = 0;
private int[] array;
```

JVM sets `int` fields to zero by default. Consider this:

```
private int size;
private int currentIndex;
private int[] array;
```

**Advice 4**

```
public int[] Get() {
    return array;
}
```

Wrong. Please, don't expose data structure related internals to the outside world.

**Advice 5**

Method names must come in `camelCase`, not in `PascalCase`.

**Advice 6**

```
public MyArray(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    array = new int[size];
}
```

What?! Your MyArray (no pun intended) is of size of `size` at the very beginning? In the state where all the "elements" are 0?

**Advice 7 (ignore)**

Actually, it seems to me that you don't need to keep `size` at all. Judging from your implementation we have always `size == array.length`. Ditch the `size` and rely on `array.length`; much easier to follow.

**Advice 8**

I suggest you add a `get(int)` method for accessing the data.

**Advice 9**

In `IncreaseArraySize()`, you could use `System.arraycopy`. Most likely, it will copy faster on large arrays.

Comment: For advice 1, my intention was for the array to be empty if size isn't specified in the constructor and calling Push would increase the size anyways. I also don't understand advice 6, apart from the fact that it does actually makes sense to completely get rid of `size`.

Comment: The array size needs to be tracked separately for `IncreaseArraySize` to work. Otherwise you have to resize the array every time an element is added or removed, which is very inefficient.

Comment: @EricStein  In this program, array size is stored at `currentIndex`.  The variable called `size` is actually the capacity, which is always the same as the `array.length`.  I.e. your analysis is correct (you need two sizes), but due to bad naming, it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>     private int size = 0;
>     private int currentIndex = 0;
> ```

Given how you use these, better names would be

```
    private int capacity = 0;
    private int size = 0;
```

But as [@coderodde already noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/267891/71574), it would make more sense to get the capacity from `array.length` rather than maintain it separately.

I would also rename `array` to `data`, but that's a more arguable point.